If $A\subseteq B$, then $B^{\perp} \subseteq \Pi(B\mid A^{\perp})$
Suppose A, B are closed linear subspace of Hilbert space, I want to show if $A\subseteq B$, then $B^{\perp} \subseteq \Pi(B\mid A^{\perp})$, where $\Pi$ is the projection operator.
I'm not sure how to think about $(\Pi(B\mid A^{\perp}))^{\perp}$, is there any mathematical way to write it more in detail so I can continue the algebra?

Since $A\subseteq B$, we have $\Pi(B \mid A^{\perp})\subseteq B$.
Let $\ell \in B^{\perp}$, by definition, $\forall \nu\in B, \langle \ell,\nu \rangle=0$.
Therefore, $\forall m\in \Pi(B \mid A^{\perp})\subset B$, $\langle \ell,m \rangle=0$.

Hence $B^{\perp}\subseteq\Pi(B \mid A^{\perp})$.
